# Spring multi-module JPMS project - exception only in IntellIJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-webflux, java-platform-module-system

I'm learning myself Java Platform Module System, and it's going very hard. Currently I just trying figure out one problem with my IDE.
I extracted essence into separate project: https://github.com/tomi127/JPMS-problem

Long story short:
when I start `com.data.Application` through IntelliJ (PPM>Run/debug) server starts up without any problems. But when I'm making POST request to localhost:8080/storeInDB I got server error:

`Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to module spring.core`

But when I do `mvn clean package` and then run `java -jar data-module-3.1.2.jar` it works without any problems.

My questions are:

- is somehow `spring-boot-maven-plugin` disables JPMS, or IntelliJ by default uses some special parameters for JVM?
- what is best approach during development in such cases? Should I start server by maven (but it is uncomfortable) or IDE can be somehow configured to not have this type of errors?